# Tkinter Toplevel Window Cannot Be Minimized

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, toplevel

I am new to Python / Tkinter and am trying to develop an app. I have a main tk instance in one file / module and then display a second window using toplevel in a second file / window using a Menu command. When the second window is being displayed the user cannot modify anything in the main window.

However I find that the minimize command (from the Windows Title Bar) does not work for the second window (although it does work fine if both the tk instance and the toplevel instance and in the same file / module.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Code showing the problem is as follows:

File / Module 1:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Menu

from Test_Edit1 import edit_dive

# Root Window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1000x565')
root.title('Logbook')

menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

dive_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
dive_menu.add_command(label='Edit', command = lambda : edit_dive(root))
menubar.add_cascade(label="Dive", menu=dive_menu)

windowframe = tk.Frame(root, height=550, width=980)
windowframe['borderwidth'] = 3
windowframe['relief'] = 'solid'

label = tk.Label(windowframe, height=1, width=40, text="Display Edit Window from Dive Menu Above!", font=("Arial", 14), bd=2, relief="sunken", pady=10)
label.pack(side="top")


windowframe.pack(side="top")
windowframe.propagate(0)

root.mainloop()
```

File / Module 2 "Test_Edit1.py":

```
import tkinter as tk


def edit_dive(root):

    def save_new_data():    
        edit_window.destroy()

    edit_font = "AcPlus IBM VGA 9x14"
    edit_bg = "#c5c9c7" #xkcd:silver
    edit_button_fg = "black"
    edit_button_bg = "#d1b26f"  #xkcd:tan

    edit_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    edit_window.title("Edit Dive")
    edit_window.geometry("900x615")
    edit_window['background'] = edit_bg
    edit_window.focus_set()
    edit_window.grab_set()
    

    ewindowframe = tk.Frame(edit_window, height=595, width=880)
    ewindowframe['borderwidth'] = 3
    ewindowframe['relief'] = 'solid'
    ewindowframe['background'] = edit_bg

    elabel = tk.Label(ewindowframe, height=1, width=40, text="This Window Cannot Be Minimized!", font=("Arial", 14), bd=2, relief="sunken", pady=10)
    elabel.pack(side="top")

    ebuttonok = tk.Button(ewindowframe, text = "OK", font=(edit_font, 14),
                    fg=edit_button_fg, bg=edit_button_bg,
                    activebackground=edit_button_bg,
                    height =1,
                    width = 4,
                    command=save_new_data)

    ebuttoncancel = tk.Button(ewindowframe, text = "Cancel", font=(edit_font, 14),
                    fg=edit_button_fg, bg=edit_button_bg,
                    activebackground=edit_button_bg,
                    height =1,
                    width = 8,
                    command=edit_window.destroy)


    ewindowframe.pack(side="top")
    ewindowframe.propagate(0)
    ebuttonok.pack(side="left")
    ebuttoncancel.pack(side="right")

    edit_window.mainloop()
```

Thanks.

Comment: It may be because `edit_window.grab_set()` prevents the window from minimized.  If this window is minimized, where will be those mouse and keyboard events be dispatched since the `grab_set()` is not released yet?

Comment: Thanks for this. Indeed if I remove the grab_set then the window can be minimized but then the user can interact with the main display which is not the desired behaviour. Do you mean that tkinter deliberately disallows the minimize button when grab_set is used? So there is no way to achieve what I want?

Comment: My intention for when the second window is minimized is that mouse / keyboard events go to other windows applications eg browser, email app etc. The main window is not a full screen window.

Comment: `grab_set()` is application-wise, so each application has its mouse/keyboard handler independent to other applications.

Comment: Thanks. So it seems there is no way to achieve my desired behavior? With grab_set the toplevel window cannot be minimized?

Comment: Strangely enough when I generate a matplotlib plot window from my main tkinter window then the matplotlib window CAN be minimized.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to solve it somehow?

Comment: Hi, sorry but I couldn't find a solution. I still have the same problem.